# Can you cancel/invalidate a CheckoutId?

Tags: dwolla

I am using the off-site gateway, and I am locking my shopping cart upon choosing Dwolla for payment, but if the user cancels, I want to be able to unlock the cart and not allow the user to use the generated CheckoutId for purchase. Any direction on this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've set a value for "redirect" in your request to https://www.dwolla.com/payment/request (e.g "https://www.myurl.com/redirect"), a customer who cancels will end up here:

```
https://www.myurl.com/redirect?error=failure&error_description=User Cancelled
```

From there, it's a simple matter to check the query string. This part depends on your language, but in PHP you can `$_GET["error_description"]` and see if it's "User Cancelled" - if so, unlock the cart. The next time the user goes through the checkout process, they'll trigger another payment request, which will respond with a new CheckoutId.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to invalidate a checkout session... On the other hand, though, checkout sessions invalidate themselves after 15 minutes of being created, or after first complete usage; whichever comes first...